# Specific floor - how to do?

Tags: materials, shaders

could someone help me to achieve this specific floor? I'm trying with the Noise Texture but I don't know how to do the metalic edges.

[image]

Comment: If you follow the answer above, just increase the Randomness (currently at 0) of the Voronoi Texture connected to the White Noise texture to make your ground less "grid-like" and more like what's in your image.

Comment: Thanks! This is it!